# Paper theme on Ubuntu Unity

Tags: unity, themes

I can't install the paper theme on Ubuntu Unity. The strange thing is that it seems to work well when using root user but is not working as I would expect in a simple user.

[image]

Comment: Paper gtk theme is intented to be used with Gnome Shell and it's tittlebars , not Unity.

Comment: @xangua: Can you please convert your comment to an answer?

Answer (score -1):

As you can see in [screen captures](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Paper?content=169768) Paper gtk theme is intented to be used with Gnome Shell and it's "tittlebars".

Other desktops like Unity won't provide an ideal experience.